# Transportation Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, modeling, network-flow

I want to create a transportation model. I have identified importing and exporting countries with their estimated demand and supply. The cost of transportation per one uni is already calculated for each ex- and importer. Some exporters transport the hydrogen by ship and others by pipeline.

The problem I have is that I need to introduce losses when it is transported by ship. About 20% is lost and won't reach the importer. For pipeline transport there is no losses. I am having trouble to implement this into the objective function or the constraints. Is there a way to integrate this into the model?

[image]

Comment: Is the shipping loss really 20% Maybe the loss is stochastic? is that variability significant relative to what you care about?

Comment: *generalized transportation problem*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an index to the $x$ variables to indicate whether transport is via pipeline or by ship: $x_{ij}^k$ denotes the quantity shipped on link $(i,j)$ via transport mode $k\in\{\mbox{pipeline, ship}\}$.

The problem becomes:
$$
\min \sum_k\sum_i\sum_jc_{ij}^kx_{ij}^k 
$$
subject to

- supply constraints:
  $$
  \sum_k\sum_jx_{ij}^k \le a_i \quad \forall i \tag{1}
  $$
- demand constraints:
  $$
  \sum_k\sum_ix_{ij}^k \ge b_j \quad \forall j \tag{2}
  $$

To take into account $20\%$ loss when transported by ship, you can consider that a dummy copy of node $j$ absorbs the $20\%$ loss. Constraints $(2)$ should be modified as follows:

$$
\sum_k\sum_ix_{ij}^k \ge b_j + 0.2\sum_ix_{ij}^{\mbox{ship}}\quad \forall j \tag{3}
$$

Alternatively, as proposed by @Sune, you could simply say that only $80\%$ of the shipped quantity reaches the destination:

$$
\sum_ix_{ij}^{\mbox{pipeline}} + 0.8\sum_ix_{ij}^{\mbox{ship}} \ge b_j \quad \forall j \tag{4}
$$

Both constraints are of course equivalent, as
$$
\sum_k\sum_ix_{ij}^k = \sum_ix_{ij}^{\mbox{pipeline}} +0.8\sum_ix_{ij}^{\mbox{ship}} +0.2\sum_ix_{ij}^{\mbox{ship}} \tag{5}
$$

Comment: Would this be easier, if you simply say that only 80% of the shipped quantity reaches the destination? Using your variables, it could be something like $\sum_{i} x_{ij}^{pipeline}+0.8 \sum_{i} x_{ij}^{ship}\geq b_j$

Comment: Yes that looks good to me! I will add it as an alternative.

Comment: yes, in this case don't define the option that is not available. Likewise, if a link does not exist in the initial transportation problem, variable $x_{ij}$ is not defined for this link. In other words, $x_{ij}^k$ is defined only when possible, not for all $i,j,k$.

Comment: if you really don't want to work with index $k$, you could write constraint $(4)$ as follows:  $$\sum_{i|(i,j)\mbox{is via pipeline}}x_{ij} + 0.8\sum_{i|(i,j)\mbox{is via ship}} x_{ij}\ge b_j$$

Comment: @anton You might even generalise it a bit and define a parameter $0 \leq \alpha_{ij} \leq 1$ denoting the proportion lost one arc $(i,j)$ and then define the constraints as $\sum_{i} (1-\alpha_{ij})x_{ij}\geq b_j$ for all $j=1,\dots,m$. Then you would have $\alpha_{ij}=0.2$ if the transport mode from $i$ to $j$ is by ship, and $\alpha_{ij}=0$ if it is by pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below as:
$\sum_{i}(x_{i,j}P_i + 0.8x_{i,j}(1-P_i)) \ge b_j \quad \forall j$
where known parameter
$P_i = \begin{cases}
1, \text{if transport by pipe from i}  \\
0, \text{by ship}
\end{cases}$

Edit:
correction made as suggested below.